# how to say this in another words with adverb?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

> I wanted to look around the whole park which was surrounded with forest and spend quality time enjoying the view slowly, relaxedly.

This is what I want to say but sounds too tedious(?), boring and lengthy. Is there some kind of proper adverb to express something like relaxedly, slowly, carelessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *verb* that comes to mind that describes this action is **wander**, which means to go about from place to place usually without a plan or definite purpose, and can be used to describe a situation where [one walks around slowly in a relaxed way or without any clear purpose or direction.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wander)

For example:

> We spent the morning **wandering** around the old part of the city.

Another possibility is **stroll**, which, in a similar fashion to *wander*, means to walk in a slow, relaxed manner, especially for pleasure.

> I **strolled** around the old part of the city.
>
> I went for a **stroll** in the park.

If you wish to expand upon *stroll*, and reenforce the point that your walk in the park is done in a relaxed way, without hurrying, then **leisurely** can be used as an adverb in this case, and indeed, is often used in conjunction with *stroll* to describe a relaxed and unhurried walk somewhere.

> I took a **leisurely stroll** in the park this morning.